# query for top child items with Entity Framework (DbSet)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a list of Order objects. Each Order object has a list of OrderItems. The OrderItem object has a ProductId, and quantity property.

Given a list of Order objects (ex: var orders = _dbContext.Orders;)
how can I find my top selling ProductIds (based on total quantities over all the orders in my list)?

I guess I'm looking for a LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
orders.SelectMany(o=> o.OrderItems).OrderByDescending(oi=> oi.quantity).Take(5)
```

I would be careful at the generated sql though, sometimes it gets ugly.

Comment: Thank you! How does one "peek" at the generated SQL?

Comment: I use Sql Profiler for that. If you have Sql Server Management Studio you should be able to find it under the file menu: Tools>SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Just if it helps anyone now: there is nice profiler: http://stackify.com/prefix for free that allows users to analyse performance including sql commands